# How to reorder a python OrderedDict using cascading list values

Tags: python, python-3.x, ordereddictionary, ordereddict

I've seen simpler examples of this but I'm trying to get a bit more complex and can't work it out.

If I have an OrderedDict in which the key describes a person and the value is a list of their [age, gender, hairColor].

```
from collections import OrderedDict
myOD = OrderedDict(adultMale1=[50, 'male', 'grey'], babyFemale=[1, 'female', 'red'], teenMale=[13, 'male', 'blonde'], teenFemale=[13, 'female', 'red'], adultMale2=[50, 'male', 'blonde'])
print myOD.keys()
# Result: myOD:  ['teenMale', 'babyFemale', 'adultMale2', 'teenFemale', 'adultMale1']
```

What I want is to sort the OrderedDict first by age, then by gender, and then by hairColor. This would then be the **correct** result I'm looking for.

```
# Result: ['babyFemale', 'teenFemale', 'teenMale', 'adultMale2', 'adultMale1']
```

I have figured out a way to sort by age.

```
sortAgeList = []
for v in myOD.values():
    sortAgeList.append(v[0])
sortAgeList.sort()

myNewOD = OrderedDict()
for age in sortAgeList:
    for key, value in myOD.items():
        if value[0] == age:
            myNewOD[key] = myOD[key]
print 'myNewOD: ', myNewOD.keys()  
# Result: myNewOD:  ['babyFemale', 'teenMale', 'teenFemale', 'adultMale2', 'adultMale1']
```

However, I've tried multiple ways to extrapolate this approach to then re-sort any tie-breakers that are the same age and then again any tie-breakers that are the same gender, but it's getting really complex and I keep thinking there must be a simpler way.

I'm hoping someone out there has an idea to help me out. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Do you need this to be compatible with Python 2.7 or is Python 3.+ usable for you ?

Comment: Side note: Your code is still in Python 2, with `print` as a statement instead of a function. If you switch to Python >3.6 (and you should), the normal `dict` class always retains its insertion order so you won't need the `OrderedDict` class.

Comment: I'm fine with Python 3+. I only used an OrderedDict because of things I read on this site. Maybe I was reading the rong things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default sort order is already [lexicographic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order).

```
>>> sorted(myOD, key=myOD.get)
['babyFemale', 'teenFemale', 'teenMale', 'adultMale2', 'adultMale1']
```

Therefore:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(myOD.items(), key=itemgetter(1)))
OrderedDict([('babyFemale', [1, 'female', 'red']),
             ('teenFemale', [13, 'female', 'red']),
             ('teenMale', [13, 'male', 'blonde']),
             ('adultMale2', [50, 'male', 'blonde']),
             ('adultMale1', [50, 'male', 'grey'])])
```

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks wim. I'm going to have to read up on itemgetter because if I'm being honest I don't really know why this works or what that's doing.